# 500 internal error in website after moving

Tags: .htaccess, error-handling, internal-server-error

We have moved our website to a new hosting provider and we have made a new database and imported the old one in this one. When we go to the website we get a 500 internal error caused by the .htacces, but don't know why it is not working at the new server and not at the old one.

you can find the site at: http://deteakspecialist.nl.webhosting72.transurl.nl/

The .htacces looks like:

```
IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
AuthName deteakspecialist.nl

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^callme$ index.php?p=callme [L]
RewriteRule ^callmeok$ index.php?p=callmeok [L]
RewriteRule ^cart$ index.php?p=cart [L]
RewriteRule ^contact$ index.php?p=contact [L]
RewriteRule ^links$ index.php?p=links [L]
RewriteRule ^newsletter$ index.php?p=newsletter [L]
RewriteRule ^newsletterok$ index.php?p=newsletterok [L]
RewriteRule ^order$ index.php?p=order [L]
RewriteRule ^orderok$ index.php?p=orderok [L]
RewriteRule ^payment$ index.php?p=payment [L]
RewriteRule ^product/(.*?)/.*?$ index.php?p=product&i=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^productgroup/(.*?)/.*?$ index.php?p=productgroup&i=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^productgroups/(.*?)/.*?$ index.php?p=productgroups&i=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^productimage/(.*?)/.*?$ /media/product/$1.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^productimagethumb/(.*?)/.*?$ /media/product/thumb/$1.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^productinfo/(.*?)/.*?$ index.php?p=productinfo&i=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^productinfook/(.*?)/.*?$ index.php?p=productinfook&i=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^project$ index.php?p=project [L]
RewriteRule ^search$ index.php?p=search&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^service$ index.php?p=service [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap$ index.php?p=sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^Teak-tuinmeubelen$ index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^terms$ index.php?p=terms [L]
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?p=404
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^deteakspecialist\.nl$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.deteakspecialist\.nl$
RewriteRule ^teakhouten\-tuinmeubelen\.php$       "http\:\/\/www\.teaktuinmeubelen\.nl\/teakhouten\-tuinmeubelen" [R=301,L]
```

The error we see in our error log looks like:

```
[Wed Mar 11 10:52:23.874485 2015] [core:alert] [pid 79734] [client 92.70.27.237:50770] /sites/deteakspecialist.nl/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'order', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Does someone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

> [Wed Mar 11 10:52:23.874485 2015] [core:alert] [pid 79734] [client
>   92.70.27.237:50770] /sites/deteakspecialist.nl/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'order', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not
>   included in the server configuration

It's most likely caused because you were probably using `Apache 2.2` and your new host is probably using `Apache 2.4` it makes a big difference. Things have changed and you need to check these things before migrating.

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
```

Those lines are not used in `Apache 2.4` anymore. So you need to convert your settings to use the new `Require all granted`. Side note, your rule seems to be conflicting anyway.

Most likely the host does not have the `mod_access_compat` enabled. So it's just going to throw an error. Just go through and update your config.

**You should always check what versions of software is being used on a host before moving your site.** Everything from PHP versions, Web server, database etc. Because the wrong version could break your code and you will have to correct the code to make it work with that version.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#run-time